# Is Jena rdfs-aware?

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, rdfs

I am following some examples regarding SPARQL and OWL, and the examples use concepts such as defining a class. The explanation says this will work on an RDFS-aware SPARQL processor. Is Jena such a processor? I don't really understand what the term means.

EDIT: And is it OWL-aware?

EDIT: Seems JENA is not RDFS or OWL-aware, but my tests worked fine using `pellet`, which is an opensource OWL-aware processor

Answer (score 1):

You can query a Jena InfModel with the SPARQL processor -- that how to get RDFS inferences, it's not built-into the normal SPARQL processor but into the data access.